How to find this four-dimensional integral as an iterated integral with Mathematica?
I mean the following integral $$\int\limits _{[0,1]^4}\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}\,dx_1dx_2dy_1dy_2 .$$
Its value is  the average length of a random interval in the unit square (see, for example, MathWorld). Mathematica finds a multi-dimensional integral as an iterated integral. There are $4!=24$ variants to do it.
Let us consider the first four items:
p = Permutations[{{x1, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1}, {y1, 0, 1}, {y2, 0, 1}}][[1 ;; 4]];
ParallelTable[Integrate[Sqrt[(x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2],i[[1]], i[[2]], i[[3]], i[[4]]], {i, p}]


{1/240 (32 + 16 Sqrt[2] + (320 + 15 I) \[Pi] + 230 ArcSinh[1] +  30 ArcTanh[Sqrt[2]] + 30 Log[99 - 70 Sqrt[2]]),  1/240 (32 + 16 Sqrt[2] + (320 + 15 I) \[Pi] + 230 ArcSinh[1] +  30 ArcTanh[Sqrt[2]] + 30 Log[99 - 70 Sqrt[2]]),  1/240 (32 + 16 Sqrt[2] + (120 + 15 I) \[Pi] - 60 ArcCoth[Sqrt[2]] +  260 ArcSinh[1] + 30 ArcTanh[Sqrt[2]] + 25 Log[99 - 70 Sqrt[2]]),  1/240 (32 + 16 Sqrt[2] + (120 + 15 I) \[Pi] - 60 ArcCoth[Sqrt[2]] +  230 ArcSinh[1] + 30 ArcTanh[Sqrt[2]] + 20 Log[99 - 70 Sqrt[2]])}

N[%]


{4.7102 + 0. I, 4.7102 + 0. I, 2.0922 + 0. I, 2.0922 + 0. I}

The calculation of each integral in 14.1 on Windows  takes approximately 15 minutes for me.
The rest of the iterated integrals produce similar results, some of those numerically equal  4.7102 + 0. I
and some of those numerically equal 2.0922 + 0. I (the executed *.nb file on demand).
All the results of the iterated integrations are not correct since the distance between two points in the unit square is less than or equal to $\sqrt 2$
and
NIntegrate[Sqrt[(x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2],{x1,0,1},{x2,0,1},{y1,0,1},{y2,0,1},AccuracyGoal->8,PrecisionGoal->8,Method->"LocalAdaptive"] 


0.521404

and
Mean[TransformedDistribution[Sqrt[(x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2], {x1, y1, x2, y2} \[Distributed]
UniformDistribution[{{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}}]]] // ComplexExpand


2/15 + Sqrt[2]/15 + 5/48 Log[99 - 70 Sqrt[2]] -  11/192 Log[-1 + Sqrt[2]] + 173/192 Log[1 + Sqrt[2]]

confirm it. I am able to correctly calculate the integral under consideration by the change of variables which simplifies the integrand
in such a way.
IntegrateChangeVariables[Inactive[Integrate][Sqrt[(x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2],{x1,0,1},
{x2,0,1},{y1,0,1},{y2,0,1}],{p,q,r,s},{p==x1,q==y1,r==x2-x1,s==y2-y1}]


Inactive[Integrate][Sqrt[r^2 + s^2], {p, 0, 1}, {q, 0, 1},  {r, -p, 1 - p}, {s, -q, 1 - q}]

Activate[ Inactive[Integrate][Sqrt[r^2 + s^2], {p, 0, 1}, {q, 0, 1},
 {r, -p, 1 - p}, {s, -q,  1 - q}], Unevaluated[Integrate]] // ComplexExpand


2/15+Sqrt[2]/15-1/64 Log[1-1/Sqrt[2]]+1/64 Log[1+1/Sqrt[2]]+13/96 Log[99-70 Sqrt[2]]-1/16 Log[-1+Sqrt[2]]+101/96 Log[1+Sqrt[2]]

Are there other ways to correctly find the integral under consideration as an iterated integral? I'd like to notice that the way to find the average length of a random interval in the unit square
in Trott, M. "The Mathematica Guidebooks Additional Material: Average Distance Distribution." http://www.mathematicaguidebooks.org/additions.shtml#S_1_14
does not consist in the calculation of an iterated integral for the integral under consideration.

Also I don't find the way in  Trott, M. "The Mathematica Guidebooks Additional Material: Average Distance Distribution." http://www.mathematicaguidebooks.org/additions.shtml#S_1_14  reliable though the answer is correct: the integration of DiracDelta works by the rule "As much as is necessary".

I got yet another value 2.6158 : Integrate[Sqrt[(x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2], {x1, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1}, {y1, 0, 1}, {y2, 0, 1}] produced 1/60 (8 + 4 Sqrt[2] + 40 \[Pi] + 50 ArcSinh[1] + 15/2 Log[99/2 - 35 Sqrt[2]] + 15 Log[2 + Sqrt[2]]). Version 14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024).

@A.Kato: Thank you. How about other iterated integrals?

As you said, the computation takes a lot of time, so I just tried another case, {x1, 0, 1}, {y1, 0, 1}, {y2, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1}. Then I got the correct answer.

@A.Kato:  It's kind of you. Nice to hear it.

My somewhat older Mathematica version v12.2 isn't able to symbollically evaluate the integral.
But numerical evalution gives same result 0.521396 for all 24 cases
permu = Permutations[{{x1, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1}, {y1, 0, 1}, {y2, 0,1}}];
Map[Apply[NIntegrate,Join[{Sqrt[(x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2]}, #, {Method ->"LocalAdaptive"}]] &, permu]
(*{0.521396, 0.521396, 0.521396, 0.521396, 0.521396, 0.521396, \
0.521396, 0.521396, 0.521396, 0.521396, 0.521396, 0.521396, 0.521396, \
0.521396, 0.521396, 0.521396, 0.521396, 0.521396, 0.521396, 0.521396, \
0.521396, 0.521396, 0.521396, 0.521396}*)


UlrichNeumann (@ does not work.): Thank you for your comment.  The true numeric value is 0.521405. On 12.02.22 some symbolic values of those iterated integrals were true [CASE:4903595].

@ works just fine. But only if one has the courtesy of using it.
